# Using components to access the store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a i18n component for translations, this component accesses the store and renders the translation. However i would like to use that component to return the translation as a string instead of a react element. How can i do that?

Is there any way i can access the store to obtain the translation instead of having to proxy it through a component?

```
interface StateProps {
  dictionary: Dictionary
}

interface DisplayProps extends StateProps {
  i18n: string
  values?: ValueObject
}

/** Renders translations */
class Translate extends PureComponent<DisplayProps, State> {
  public render () {
    const dict = this.props.dictionary
    return this.props.i18n && e(Fragment, {},
      dict
        ? translate(dict)(this.props.i18n, this.props.values)
        : this.props.i18n
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: State): StateProps => ({
  dictionary: state.i18n
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Translate)
```

Comment: Stores are just objects that you can call things on, like `getState`. All you need is a reference to the store. All `connect` does is provide convenient, React-like bindings to the store for components under the `Provider`.

Comment: If you export your store from the file where you create it with createStore(), you can import it to other files as normal and then use store.getState() or store.subscribe(listener) to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the answers provided (thank you!) i ended up exporting the store and accessing it directly.